# Reactjs Class to Functional component problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having hard time trying to convert class component to functional component. Requesting your help in this please.

Class code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import GenericChartComponent from "../GenericChartComponent";
import { drawOnCanvas } from "./EdgeCoordinate";

export default class PriceCoordinate extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.saveNode = this.saveNode.bind(this);
        this.drawOnCanvas = this.drawOnCanvas.bind(this);
    }

    saveNode(node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    drawOnCanvas(ctx) {     
        drawOnCanvas(ctx, props);
    }

    render() {
        const ref = { ref: this.saveNode } ;

        return <GenericChartComponent           
            canvasDraw={this.drawOnCanvas}           
        />;
    }
}
```

I have tried to do it this way, but imported function drawOnCanvas is not getting called, also this.node am not sure how to set it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import GenericChartComponent from "../GenericChartComponent";
import { drawOnCanvas } from "./EdgeCoordinate";

function PriceCoordinate(props){
    const node = null; 

    const saveNode= (node) =>{
        this.node = node;
    }

    const drawOnCanvas = (ctx) => {     
        drawOnCanvas(ctx, props);
    }
     
    const ref = { ref: this.saveNode } ;

    return <GenericChartComponent           
        canvasDraw={this.drawOnCanvas}           
    />;    
}
```

Comment: What uses `ref` in your class component's `render`? That's the only thing referring to `saveNode`, and nothing ever uses it. What is `saveNode` for?

Comment: Your `class` component also tries to use `props` *without* `this` in `drawOnCanvas`, but there is no in-scope `props` there. We really can't help you based on the `class` component you've shown, given the issues with it, other than to say: 1. You're shadowing the outer `drawOnCanvas` identifier with  your inner one, so the inner `drawOnCanvas` would be calling itself if you were successfully calling it. You need to change the name of one or the other. 2. You're using `this`, but you almost never use `this` in function...

Comment: ...components, because React doesn't set `this` to the component instance when calling your function. If you need per-instance information, use state (if it affects rendering) or a ref (if not).

Answer (score 1):

there are four things here

- one you where trying to assign a parameter to a constant in the
  save node function
- two you cannot use 'this' keyword in functions only in classes
- three why is the ref variable even there in the first place
- four u are using drawOnCanvas twice one from the import and one from the function which is an error

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import GenericChartComponent from "../GenericChartComponent";
import { drawOnCanvas } from "./EdgeCoordinate";

function PriceCoordinate(props){
    let node; 

    const saveNode= (node2) =>{
        node = node2;
    }

    const draw = (ctx) => {     
        drawOnCanvas(ctx, props);
    }
     
    const ref = { ref: saveNode } ;

    return <GenericChartComponent           
        canvasDraw={draw}           
    />;    
}
```

Comment: 1. Code dumps are not useful answers, please say *what* you did, and *why*. 2. The `node` stuff makes no sense here, a new `node` variable is created on every render and not saved anywhere. Although the `class` component is incomplete or incorrect, if you're going to post an answer, it would make sense to attempt to handle the `node` stuff correctly and explain why you can't just assign to a local variable.

Comment: If you look at the class code, in the renderer its calling the class function, and then in the class function it is calling the imported function.